# array.pop() not a function problem, javascipt

Tags: javascript

I have this problem often with array methods, so i quess theres something im missing out.
I tried finding solution, but failed.
If you have any clue why it says that array is not a function (I am using it on an array), please tell. Also, a,b,c are defined in html.

```js
function jes(a, b, c) {
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b);
    c = parseInt(c);
    var arej = [a, b, c];
    var si = arej.pop();
    arej = arej.unshift(si);
    var ki = arej.pop();
    arej = arej.unshift(ki);
    var bi = arej.pop();
    arej = arej.unshift(bi);
    alert(arej);
}
```

Comment: Have you done troubleshooting on which one of the `pop` calls are failing? and what is the array value in that case?

Comment: Yes, its the second pop() call on line 8. It also says array is not defined and im not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unshift()` method returns the new length of the array. So, you array is reassigned as a Number type. Hence you get the error.

The array is changed in-situ. You can make the changes as follows:

```
function jes(a, b, c) {
a = parseInt(a);
b = parseInt(b);
c = parseInt(c);
var arej = [a, b, c];
var si = arej.pop();
arej.unshift(si);
var ki = arej.pop();
arej.unshift(ki);
var bi = arej.pop();
arej.unshift(bi);
alert(arej);
```

}

Comment: Thank you, My msitake for remembering wrong what unshift return

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) alters given array, instead of returning a modified version. It returns the length of the altered array.

```
function jes(a,b,c)
{
    a=parseInt(a);
    b=parseInt(b);
    c=parseInt(c);
    var arej=[a,b,c];
    var si=arej.pop();
    arej.unshift(si);
    var ki = arej.pop();
    arej.unshift(ki);
    var bi=arej.pop();
    arej.unshift(bi);
    alert(arej);
}
```

you should have:

- figured out where it failed
- then looked up the method that failed

Comment: Thank you, My msitake for remembering wrong what unshift returns.